# Unable to retrieve results from site

Tags: php, json

Everything's working fine but I was unable to retrieve the total number of results from the site (faroo)..

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['q']))
    {
        $q = $_GET['q'];
        $p = $_GET['p'];
        $page = file_get_contents('http://www.faroo.com/api?q=' . $q 
                . '&start=' . $p . '&l=en&key='.$myownkey.'&src=web&f=json');

        // echo $page->{'count'}; //this too not working

        $dat_array = json_decode($page, true);
        echo $dat_array->{'count'}; //not woking.
    }
?>
```

where am I going wrong?

Comment: what is the content of `$page`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> json_decode($page, true);

The second parameter as "true" turns the data into an associative array rather than an object. To access the data this should work:

```
echo $dat_array['count'];
```

Comment: echo $dat_array['count']; @Luke wenke ...thank you problem resolved.